# AWS instances launched without my intervention

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to Amazon Web Services (AWS). I've followed some of Amazon tutorials on AWS and thus I subscribed to the **free tier**.

I created some EC2 instances which I can see running in my AWS console.

However, **after I stop and terminate these EC2 instances, others** (with the same names) **are relaunched automatically**. Why is that? I thought I could only launch an instance manually with the Launch Instance button.

Answer (score 3):

You have most likely created an [Auto Scaling Group](https://aws.amazon.com/de/autoscaling/) in one of the tutorials. In short, Auto Scaling Groups automatically creates and replaces  EC2 instances.

You can find your Auto Scaling Groups [in the EC2 console](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/autoscaling/home?region=us-west-2#AutoScalingGroups:). Once you delete them, your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Web Services offers several possibilities to automatically lunch instances. None of these are activated by default.

You might have created an  [Auto Scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) group or an [Elastic Beanstalk Environment](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk). Either way, you want to delete the instance in the respective section within the AWS console.

Most of the beginner Tutorials also have a "Cleaning Up" section, which gives you detailed instructions on how to remove all created systems and avoid charges.

Comment: thank you; indeed, I had Auto Scaling; I take this opportunity to say that Amazon AWS documentation totally sucks